# Accepting arguments in a console application with managed code in C++

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I attempted to use this code to accept arguments from a console application. Unfortunately all I get are boolean values for some weird reason. I'm not sure what's happening. I think I might be mixing namespaces or something. Anyone?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Text;

void uploadFile(String^ strFileName, String^ strServerName, String^ strUserName, String^         strPassword);
void prompt();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if (argc < 9)
{
    prompt();
}
else if (argc == 9)
{
    char* fileName;
    char* serverName;
    char* userName;
    char* password;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i] == "-f")
            fileName = argv[i + 1];
        else if (argv[i] == "-s")
            serverName = argv[i + 1];
        else if (argv[i] == "-u")
            userName = argv[i + 1];
        else if (argv[i] = "-p")
            password = argv[i + 1];
        else
            prompt();
        Console::WriteLine(argv[i]);
    }
    String ^strFileName = gcnew String(fileName);
    String ^strServerName = gcnew String(serverName);
    String ^strUserName = gcnew String(userName);
    String ^strPassword = gcnew String(password);
    Console::WriteLine(argv[1]);
    Console::WriteLine(strFileName);
    uploadFile(strFileName, strServerName, strUserName, strPassword);
}
else
{
    prompt();
}
}

void uploadFile(String^ strFileName, String^ strServerName, String^ strUserName, String^ strPassword)
{
if (!strServerName->StartsWith("ftp://"))
{
    String^ host = "ftp://";
    host += strServerName;
    strServerName = host;
}
String^ path = Directory::GetCurrentDirectory();
WebClient^ wclient = gcnew WebClient();
wclient->Credentials = gcnew NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword);
String^ destFileName = path;
destFileName += strFileName;
Console::WriteLine(destFileName);
Console::WriteLine(strServerName);
/*array<Byte>^response = wclient->UploadFile(strServerName, destFileName);
if (response->Length > 0)
{
    ASCIIEncoding^ ascii = gcnew ASCIIEncoding;
    String^ decoded = ascii->GetString(response);
    Console::WriteLine("Response: {0}", decoded);
}*/
}
void prompt()
{
Console::WriteLine("Usage: ftpCLI.exe -f <filename> -s <server> -u <username> -p    <password>\n");
Console::ReadLine();
Environment::Exit(1);
}
```

And for anyone interested here is the program with the resolution implemented and completed.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Text;

void uploadFile(String^ strFileName, String^ strServerName, String^ strUserName, String^     strPassword);
void prompt();

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if (argc < 9)
{
    prompt();
}
else if (argc == 9)
{
    char* fileName;
    char* serverName;
    char* userName;
    char* password;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-f") == 0)
            fileName = argv[i + 1];
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-s") == 0)
            serverName = argv[i + 1];
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-u") == 0)
            userName = argv[i + 1];
        else if (strcmp(argv[i], "-p") == 0)
            password = argv[i + 1];
        Console::WriteLine(argv[i]);
    }
    String ^strFileName = gcnew String(fileName);
    String ^strServerName = gcnew String(serverName);
    String ^strUserName = gcnew String(userName);
    String ^strPassword = gcnew String(password);
    Console::WriteLine(argv[1]);
    uploadFile(strFileName, strServerName, strUserName, strPassword);
}
else
{
    prompt();
}
}

void uploadFile(String^ strFileName, String^ strServerName, String^ strUserName, String^ strPassword)
{
if (!strServerName->StartsWith("ftp://"))
{
    String^ host = "ftp://";
    host += strServerName;
    strServerName = host;
}
String^ path = Directory::GetCurrentDirectory();
WebClient^ wclient = gcnew WebClient();
wclient->Credentials = gcnew NetworkCredential(strUserName, strPassword);
String^ destFileName = strServerName;
destFileName += "/" + strFileName;
array<Byte>^response = wclient->UploadFile(destFileName, strFileName);
if (response->Length > 0)
{
    ASCIIEncoding^ ascii = gcnew ASCIIEncoding;
    String^ decoded = ascii->GetString(response);
    Console::WriteLine("Response: {0}", decoded);
}
}
void prompt()
{
Console::WriteLine("Usage: ftpCLI.exe -f <filename> -s <server> -u <username> -p   <password>\n");
Console::ReadLine();
Environment::Exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop is troublesome:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
{
    if (argv[i] == "-f")
        fileName = argv[i + 1];
    else if (argv[i] == "-s")
        serverName = argv[i + 1];
    else if (argv[i] == "-u")
        userName = argv[i + 1];
    else if (argv[i] = "-p")
        password = argv[i + 1];
    else
        prompt();
    Console::WriteLine(argv[i]);
}
```

Lets say that the fist argument is `-f` with the filename following that. The first run through the loop you get the `-f` and extract the filename. The next iteration you however `argv[i]` will be the filename you extracted in the first iteration.

When you get an argument with a parameter (like `-f`) you need to increment `i` once extra time.

**Edit:** As noted by heavyd, the actual problem you have is probably the comparison of the string. You can not use the equality operator for raw C-style strings, you have to use e.g. [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

Like this:

```
if (strcmp(argv[i], "-f") == 0) { ... }
```

Comment: Not to mention that `argv[i] == "-f"` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Thank you. I see the flaw in the loop now. The program will terminate after it finds the file. I made the suggested changes and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In CLR console your main should be like:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
```